# How can I login to a display-less machine via ethernet?

Tags: lightdm, remote

I have two Ubuntu systems.  The first I'd like to use as a server.  Hence I don't have a display or even keyboard for it.  The other is my laptop and can connect to the network.  Upon bootup, the "server" will go to a lightdm login screen.

First thing I'd like to do is connect my server to my network.  But since I don't have a display for it, I'd like to do it somehow using my laptop.  Is there a way I can just connect my laptop to the server using ethernet and then configure it?  First step:  how do I get "in", or bypass the login screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your server boots up, even if you don't log in, it should be connected to the local network.

To log in, you should be able to use ssh:

```
ssh username@yourmachinename.local
```

If you'd like to run graphical apps on the server you can add X forwarding:

```
ssh -X username@yourmachine.local
```

Comment: The ssh command seems to work, but I can't answer the password query, even though I know the password is correct.  Any ideas?  Perhaps I need to reconfigure ssh?

Comment: Hmm that's odd.  It's usually the username and password as you log on to the system with.

Comment: I marked your answer as the solution, as it seems to be one...even if for whatever reason, it doesn't quite work.

Comment: Still not working then?  Try creating a new account on the machine, and ssh'ing in with that maybe (just to check whether it's an account problem).  You could also try `apt-cache policy openssh-server` on the server to check that ssh is installed.

Comment: There could be something restrictive in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config making the user only allowed in from a certain IP range, only with Public Key, not with password authentication, or not on a whitelist of users who *are* allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be that your trying to login as root, and its off by default, if so use your regular user

- this is in reply to your ssh problems